# Creating Coroutine for Listeners

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, swap

My main script sorts a set of balls 1 by 1, I am calling that script into this so when I [click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GALfG.png) button it will trigger sorting button and it will sort 1 by 1 by waiting in example 1-2 sec between each swapping. But when I click the button that made for triggering an automated sort in sorts immediately so in here Coroutine doesnt do what it suppose to do.

This is unsorted set of balls. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/849bj.png)
Is there any way to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


namespace Assets
{
    public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Gameobjects _Gameobjects; 
        public Button e_YourButton;
        public void Start()
        {
            Button btn = e_YourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                btn.onClick.AddListener(_Gameobjects.TaskOnClick);
                btn.onClick.AddListener(() => { _Gameobjects.Click1(); });
                StartCoroutine(Example());    
            }
        }   

        IEnumerator Example()
        {

           yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Main script;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


namespace Assets
{
    public class Gameobjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Button s_YourButton;
        [SerializeField]

        public GameObject[] Balls = new GameObject[5];

        public bool Click = false;

        private static int i = 0;
        private int j = i + 1;
        private int increasebyclick = 1;

        private Vector3 posA = Vector3.zero; //Vector3.zero is for initialization
        private Vector3 posB = Vector3.zero; //Vector3.zero is for initialization


        public GameObject[] instantiatedObjects= new GameObject[5];

        void Start()
        {
            Button btn = s_YourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            //Calls the TaskOnClick method when you click the Button
            btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
            btn.onClick.AddListener(() => { Click1(); });
            Balls[0] = GameObject.Find("5");
            Balls[1] = GameObject.Find("3");
            Balls[2] = GameObject.Find("2");
            Balls[3] = GameObject.Find("4");
            Balls[4] = GameObject.Find("1");
        }


        public void TaskOnClick()
        {

            performInsertionSort(Balls);



        }
        public void Click1()
        {
            i += increasebyclick;
            print(i);
            if (i >= 4)
            {
                i = 0;            }
        }


        private void performInsertionSort(GameObject[] Balls)
        {
            {



                        if (string.Compare(Balls[i].name, Balls[i+1].name) > 0)
                        {
                            GameObject temp = Balls[i];
                            Balls[i] = Balls[i+1];
                            Balls[i+1] = temp;

                            posA = Balls[i].gameObject.transform.position;
                            posB = Balls[i + 1].gameObject.transform.position;
                            Balls[i].gameObject.transform.position = posB;
                            Balls[i + 1].gameObject.transform.position = posA;


                            }
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a swapping function anywhere if your code. All this does is assign Listeners after a delay. It sounds like you want the delay to occur within the onClick function itself.

Comment: I will show you my main script after I upload it in several minutes.

Comment: @ryeMoss https://codeshare.io/axbz9M

Comment: Instead of posting it on a codeshare, extract the relevant code from it, and [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50625400/edit) instead

Comment: The only point at which you are starting your coroutine is in your start function. Also, the way you do it there you just start an instance of the coroutine at the end of each iteration of the loop, but since the loop is not inside a coroutine, the coroutine has no effect on the loop whatsoever. The loop is most likely done before the first coroutines' one second passed.

Comment: And some part (the loop) is missing in your second script (performInsertionSort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second script (`Gameobjects` is pretty bad naming btw) should look something like this:

```
// Don't start another sort while the current isn't finished
// Or: stop the current one with StopAllCoroutines()
bool isSorting = false;

public void TaskOnClick()
{
    if(isSorting == false)
    {
        isSorting = true;
        StartCoroutine(PerformInsertionSort());
    }
}

private IEnumerator PerformInsertionSort()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Balls.Length - 1; i++)
    {      
        if (string.Compare(Balls[i].name, Balls[i+1].name) > 0)                   
        {
            GameObject temp = Balls[i];
            Balls[i] = Balls[i+1];
            Balls[i+1] = temp;

            posA = Balls[i].gameObject.transform.position;
            posB = Balls[i + 1].gameObject.transform.position;
            Balls[i].gameObject.transform.position = posB;
            Balls[i + 1].gameObject.transform.position = posA;

            // If you want to wait only after a switch actually happend,
            // wait here.
        }

        // This is where you need to wait:
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }

    isSorting = false;
}
```

The array you sort is a member of the script so passing it to a function inside the script as parameter is meaningless.

Comment: The sorting needs to continue untill the sorting is totally done but it stops after finishing first set of balls and the balls are remains unsorted, how to fix this? I tried to reset i after reaching 4 but didn't help.

Comment: That's a matter of the sorting algorithm. I only one loop (you had no loop at all in your function), but you will need a second, inner loop. Outer loop runs from index (i) 0 to end and the inner loop from `array[i]` back to index 0 that compares backwards. Have a look at some pseudo code e.g. at the wikipedia page for insertion sort.